# The proper way to say "Mocha" the coffee drink

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

I have noticed that most of the time when I go to Starbucks and order a *mocha*, the cashier doesn't seem to understand unless I repeat it.

I am trying to think why is that the case since it is a very easy word to pronounce. I pronounce it as '*moka*' but I am wondering if I should put a light *w* 'mowka' instead? If that's the case, does this really make such a huge difference between being understood or not?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m not sure exactly what the capitals in your phonetics mean, but if they’re supposed to indicate stress, then I have to say I’ve never heard anyone say either [lɑːˈteɪ] or [ˈdʒiːəʊvɑːni]. It’s always been [ˈlɑːteɪ] and [dʒəˈvɑːni] in my experience. The diphthongs and vowel lengths are of course inevitable.

Comment: @Keeto You don’t mention what your native language is, so it’s not clear at all exactly what your _‘moka’_ means. The standard pronunciation of _mocha_ in English is [ˈməʊkə] in British English and [ˈmoʊkə] in American English. Long /o/ does include a w-ish offglide (the [ʊ]), and a native English speaker would automatically add that in—so if you’re actually pronouncing it something like IPA [ˈmoka] (which is how the Spanish pronounce it, for example), then a native English speaker might find it somewhat difficult to understand.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I can assure you that I've heard more than one mispronunciation of *latte* (typically LAH.tei and less often, la.TEI) and *Giovanni* (GEO.vahn.nee). I deliberately refrained from using [IPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet), because frankly outside the world of linguistics and ESL it's not commonly known nor understood. However I am willing to delete my comment if you delete your FIRST one (made a mistake earlier).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Most Britons I know (including myself) would pronounce it with a short "o", as if it were spelt "mocka" (IPA [ˈmɒkə]). I would consider the [ˈməʊkə] pronunciation you suggested as rather pretentious, affected, or overly American-influenced.

Comment: @PhilMJones - Given that there can be no 'correct' pronunciation, by the same token I don't see how there can be a 'pretentious' one either, unless the speaker is claiming to pronounce it the 'proper' way.

Comment: @ErikKowal - That's precisely what I meant, if "pretentious" means "attempting to impress by affecting greater importance or merit than is actually possessed." I had in mind an element of fake linguistic snobbery, derived from deliberately pronouncing a word differently from the masses in order to make oneself appear more intelligent.  Of course, as you say, one pronunciation isn't necessarily more correct than another.  However, I believe my pronunciation to be more prevalent. Incidentally, my lack of evidence is why I only commented, rather than answering.

Comment: @PhilMJones - In that case, Phil, you make a fair point, and it appears we essentially agree.

Comment: Tomato, tomato.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the online [Merriam-Webster,](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mocha?show=0&t=1410939511) *Mocha* is a small town and seaport in southwest Yemen that as early as 1773 had already given its name to the style of coffee.

The Arabic pronunciation of the name of the town can be heard [here](http://media.merriam-webster.com/soundc11/a/almuk02g.wav). *However,* nobody in the English-speaking world says the name that way, and I therefore doubt that your local Starbucks barista would understand what you meant if you used the Arabic pronunciation when ordering your coffee.

What must be remembered is that as soon as the speakers of Language A adopt a word from Language B, there is absolutely no guarantee that they will refrain from mutilating the original word in every possible way, from pronouncing it differently, to pluralizing it differently, to using it to mean something different to what it denoted in Language B.

And that is all perfectly natural and OK — it's one of those evolutionary mechanisms that operate in all languages whose speakers come into contact with outsiders.

Anyway, all this is a preamble to my conclusion, which is that there *is* no 'proper' way in English to say *mocha* — or *bourgeoisie*, or *Venezia,* or *gulag*, for that matter. Once a word has been imported from Language B by Language A, the speakers of A own it when they are speaking their own language, and they can do what they like with it. And they do. The different pronunciations of *mocha* around the world that Kyle has linked to in his answer amply demonstrate that point.

All one can say regarding its 'proper' pronunciation by speakers who have imported it into a language other than the one it came from (in this case, Arabic) is that there is likely to be a period where several different pronunciations of the newly-adopted word coexist, and that a consensus may eventually emerge regarding its usual pronunciation among the speakers of the adoptive language. That consensus too may vary from region to region and dialect to dialect.

Indeed, as far as *mocha* is concerned, I think Janus B J's comment above pretty much covers the situation as it currently applies to most native speakers of British and American English. I have reproduced the relevant part of [that comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196852/the-proper-way-to-say-mocha-the-coffee-drink#comment414988_196852) here, in case it gets deleted:

> The standard pronunciation of *mocha* in English is [ˈməʊkə] in British English and [ˈmoʊkə] in American English. Long /o/ does include a w-ish offglide (the [ʊ]), and a native English speaker would automatically add that in—so if you’re actually pronouncing it something like IPA [ˈmoka] (which is how the Spanish pronounce it, for example), then a native English speaker might find it somewhat difficult to understand.

But I wouldn't advise anyone to go around 'correcting' other people's pronunciation of the word, because they frankly wouldn't have a leg to stand on if they were challenged.

Comment: +1 But I have to tell you that the Arabic pronunciation linked was difficult for me to understand, and I am an _arabic_ native

Comment: haha I am actually Egyptian too but my question was "how to properly pronounce it in America" not the general correct pronunciation. I think I should have made that clearer in my question. But yes, Janus's comment sums it all up. This is actually what I was looking for. I was not really pronouncing the w-ish offglide.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by [ˈməʊkə] being British English.

/moka/ is the Australian way, and according to this it's the English way as well, schwa notwithstanding

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zZifMmoZJYw
...

Answer (score 1):

Please see the link below for recordings of the word.

As we know, pronunciation varies widely from region to region. These samples should give you an idea of its pronunciation in a variety of world Englishes:

[Recordings of the word "mocha" on forvo.com](http://www.forvo.com/word/mocha/#en)