# Is "sub-project" more like "support project" or "child project"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, translation

I have a controversy of my project's leader about the meaning of "sub-project". When we need to translate *sub-project* from English to our native language (Vietnamese), I think that we should understand it as *child project*, as subsets in mathematics, because without the mother project, that sub-project has no significant role in our program. However, in her opinion, it should be translate literally to *support project*, since without it, the main project's result become less significant. In other words, I define the word by its role to the whole program, she defines it by its role to the main project.

There is no definition for this word in famous dictionaries like Oxford or Merriam-Webster, except [Collins dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/subproject):

> a project that is part of a larger project

This doesn't help. Which meaning is better for *sub-project*, "support project" or "child project"?

Comment: On the basis of the information you've supplied, there are good arguments for both expressions. In such cases, sensible people who aren't trying to have the last word will agree to disagree.

Comment: This is a question about Vietnamese usage. The English usage is not in question. Seems off-topic.

Comment: @Potatoswatter if I remove the translation detail and focus on the meaning of the word, it will appear to be on topic again.

Comment: @Ooker There's no English ambiguity. The dilemma, if any, involves how things are organized in your work, and we have no idea about that. (I'd guess, though, that your boss isn't amused by taking time from your workday to quibble over her terminology.)

Comment: Are there really no other subprojects ever done in Viet Nam, that the language doesn't already have a word or phrase for it?

Comment: @JonHanna of cuourse there is a word for that, but she doesn't think that's a good choice. Not related, but do you think that we should [write *Vietnam* as one word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/196871/how-to-write-vietnamese-names-in-english-correctly-vi%e1%bb%87t-nam-to-vietnam-or)?

Comment: Does that term break down into components? If so, what would be the translation of the parts? (On the matter of *Viet Nam* vs *Vietnam*, I'd say you are more expert than I; both forms are good English but if I heard that the Vietnamese generally preferred one form over the other I'd switch my practice to match that preference).

Answer (score 3):

If I had to create a new word for *sub-project* in English that for some reason couldn't use *sub-* I would favour something using the *component*, *element*, *elementary*, *part* etc. The sub-project is after all a part of the project.

(I'd probably end up going for "child project" but that's because it's *child* is a short word in English and the metaphor is common enough, and I'd favour those over the more direct meaning of *elementary* etc.; I have no idea if either of those are true in Vietnamese, or if *elementary* is long).

I'd also definitely look to see what other people were using first, and go with what was popular as long as it wasn't totally ridiculous and perhaps even if it was, because using the same terms as everyone else is the best way to be understood.

Comment: I think *sub-project* is a good choice in this situation. *Component* and other terms which you mentioned cannot stands alone and work independent. In contrast, *sub-project* can. It's just that it has no significant role if it stands alone.

Answer (score 1):

In common usage as I know it, a "sub-project" is neither a *child project* nor a *support project*. A sub-project is ancillary to the main project- that is, it is related, but it is not subsequent (e.g. following) to the primary project. At the same time, it does not support the main project.

To take your question and use it as an example, a main project would be you seeking an answer to clarify what a "sub-project" is on Stack Exchange. A *sub-project* would be figuring out the appropriate translation or translations into Vietnamese of the English prefix "sub-" on its own- it is neither immediately supporting or reinforcing the main project, nor is it dependent upon the outcome of the main project, but it is related to and occurring at the same time as the main project. A "child project" would be dependent upon and subsequent to the main project- a child project in this example might be the composition of ten English example sentences that correctly use the phrase "sub-project." Likewise, a "Support project" would be something that is necessary for the completion of the project; for example, a "Support project" to this might be to figure out the definition of the word "project" and a suitable translation into Vietnamese.

Comment: Neithe "child" nor "support" project convey the meaning "sub-project". A sub-project is a project that is a part of another project. I do not know  how you would express that in Vietnamese.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock do people understand *sub-project* as they understand *subset* in math?

Comment: @MiguelArbusto will you suggest that *sub-project* equivalent to *related project*?